# Can't loop through a range after defining it with range.columns(n)

Tags: excel, vba

I've run into this a few times, always rather annoyingly. I can work around it, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a reason for it or an easier workaround.

I've defined a range that contains all my data with

```
Set rngAll = range("A8",cells(usedrange.rows.count,usedrange.columns.count))
```

Now I want to look through each cell in the first column of that range, and I'm trying to do this:

```
Set rngUserIDs = rngAll.columns(1)
For each rngCell in rngUserIDs
    Do Something
next rngCell
```

When I run the code, instead of looking at each individual cell in `rngUserIDs`, `rngCell` sets itself to match the entirety of `rngUserIDs`. If `rngUserIDs` = A8:A1000, instead of starting at A8 and looping down, `rngCell` immediately = A8:A1000, does its something, then exits the loop.

If I set rngUserIDs any other way, such as:

```
set rngUserIDs = Range("A8","A" & range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row)
For Each rngCell in rngUserIDs
    Do Something
next rngCell
```

it works perfectly, looking at each cell in turn.

Is there a reason for this behaviour? Is there anything I can do about it? Yes, I can work around it, but for various structural reasons it would be convenient if I could just use the first column of `rngAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the Cells property, for reasons I'm not entirely sure I'd have thought the last option was the best though as you want to restrict your range as much as possible.

```
Set rngUserIDs = rngAll.columns(1)
For each rngCell in rngUserIDs.Cells
    Do Something
next rngCell
```

Comment: One of the things I'm doing with the loop is looking for blank cells in that column. Since there could be blanks at the end of the data, while there is still data in the other columns, using `.end(xlup)` on that column could give a misleading result.

Comment: You could use Find to find the last used row in any column and then limit your code to that reduced range.